# Why does React-Bootstrap duplicate custom classNames in element?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using React-Bootstrap and I am applying some custom classes to the  component using bsClass:
Example:

```
<Button bsClass="exit action">Exit</Button>
```

The rendered HTML is:

```
<button type="button" class="exit action exit action-default">Exit the Exam</button>
```

**Why are the class names (exit & action) repeated?**

Comment: Looks to me like a bug in react-bootstrap (I was able to reproduce it easily)

Comment: Thanks and good to know.  I just started with React and React-Bootstrap, so I was trying to further my understanding, but this was stumping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `React-Bootstrap` documentation for the button component, https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/buttons/,

> **bsClass:String** - Base CSS class and prefix for the component. Generally one should only change bsClass to provide new, non-Bootstrap, CSS styles for a component.

So, `bsClass` is simply a base class which is added to the button, and the prefix for the actual styling class, to map bootstrap standards.

```
<Button>Default</Button>
```

generates

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Default</button>
```

and hence

```
<Button bsStyle="primary" bsClass="custom">Default</Button>
```

will generate

```
<button type="button" class="custom custom-primary">Default</button>
```

and in your case, by the convention, `-default` got prefixed with string you provided `exit action` and it became `exit action-default`. 
Either you have structure your css to keep this standard or ideally, it is recommend to use `bootstrapUtils` to create custom styles. https://react-bootstrap.github.io/utilities/custom-styles/